# How to enable textbox one after the other in a row if value in textbox is placed using Jquery each function

Tags: jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djQZs.png)om/drSYD.png

Comment: please provide perfect description here.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below snippet:

```
var input = $('input[type="text"]');
$.each(input, function(key, value) {
  $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Refer to the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/5cx3v29z/).

Comment: Mr. downvoter, can you explain the reason for the same?